# max_blocking_factor and index hint in for all entry select

Tags: oracle, abap, opensql

I have select looking like this:

```
SELECT  ztab1~field11 ztab1~field12 ztab2~field21
FROM ztab1
  JOIN ztab2
    ON ztab1~field10 = ztab2~field10
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_data_tab
FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_records[]
WHERE ztab1~field13 = lt_records-field13
%_HINTS ORACLE '&max_blocking_factor 500&'.
```

So, I have oracle max_blocking_factor hint there. But I also need to use an index for ztab1 table. How must the hint with max_blocking_factor and index look like?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just separate the hints with a *space*

According to the [help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenosql_db_hints.htm), that should work.

As a sidenote, if you set the max blocking factor so high, Oracle will most likely just ignore the index, hint or no hint, and perform a full table scan.

Comment: @andrás what means **==7** ? (PS: quote from the link: "One or more database hints can be specified after %_HINTS as a **blank-separated** list")

Comment: @SandraRossi it was a typo